# Type Error: unsupported operand type (s) for *: 'graphics' and 'float'

Tags: python, ооп, python-3.x, python-3.5

Суть в том, чтобы в определённом прямоугольнике внутри всё закрасить.

Не судите строго, я школьник и недавно столкнулся с программированием.
Файл main:

```
import gamefield  

i = 0  
j = 0

a = gamefield.graphics()


a.point(-300, 300, -250, 300, -250, 250, -300, 250)
```

файл gamefield:

```
import turtle

class graphics:

    def point(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, fakearg):
        turtle.speed(500)  # тут может быть любое значение от 0 и до 500 или даже больше
        turtle.fillcolor('black')
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.goto(x1, y1)
        turtle.goto(x2, y2)
        turtle.goto(x3, y3)
        turtle.goto(x4, y4)
        turtle.end_fill()
```

Если turtle.speed(something), something имеет низкое значение или строка turtle.speed() отсутствует, то выводится:

```
Type error: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'graphics' and 'int'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ХХХ-Х\Desktop\змейка python\Отладка бага\MAIN.py", line 9, in <
module>
    a.point(-300, 300, -250, 300, -250, 250, -300, 250)
  File "C:\Users\ХХХ-Х\Desktop\змейка python\Отладка бага\GAMEFIELD.py", line 8,
 in point
    turtle.goto(x1, y1)
  File "<string>", line 8, in goto
  File "C:\Users\ХХХ-Х\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\turtle.py", li
ne 1776, in goto
    self._goto(Vec2D(x, y))
  File "C:\Users\ХХХ-Х\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\turtle.py", li
ne 3165, in _goto
    diff = (end-start)
  File "C:\Users\ХХХ-Х\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\turtle.py", li
ne 262, in __sub__
    return Vec2D(self[0]-other[0], self[1]-other[1])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'graphics' and 'float'
```

Если turtle.speed() имеет большое значение, то происходит вот такая ошибка:

```
C:\Users\ХХХ-Х\Desktop\змейка python\Отладка бага>main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ХХХ-Х\Desktop\змейка python\Отладка бага\MAIN.py", line 9, in <
module>
    a.point(-300, 300, -250, 300, -250, 250, -300, 250)
  File "C:\Users\ХХХ-Х\Desktop\змейка python\Отладка бага\GAMEFIELD.py", line 9,
 in point
    turtle.goto(x1, y1)
  File "<string>", line 8, in goto
  File "C:\Users\ХХХ-Х\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\turtle.py", li
ne 1776, in goto
    self._goto(Vec2D(x, y))
  File "C:\Users\ХХХ-Х\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\turtle.py", li
ne 3195, in _goto
    self._update() #count=True)
  File "C:\Users\ХХХ-Х\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "C:\Users\ХХХ-Х\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\turtle.py", line 2651, in _update_data
    self._pencolor, self._pensize)
  File "C:\Users\ХХХ-Х\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\turtle.py", line 543, in _drawline
    cl.append(x * self.xscale)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'graphics' and 'float'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый аргумент у обычного метода такого как `graphics.point()` это всегда `self` в Питоне. Чтобы устранить ошибку, его нужно перед x1 в определении метода указать.